# How to fit a list or a dictionary of models in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a some models and I am trying to fit them all.

At the moment I have tried with a dictionary and fit them:

```
dictionary_of_models = {'catboost':CatBoostClassifier(random_state=0,), 'logistic_regression':LogisticRegression(random_state=0)}
for model in dictionary_of_models.keys():
            print(model)
            dictionary_of_models[model]=model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

But, even the model is printed out, I receive this error:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fit'
```

What's wrong with the code?

I think that a string is going passed to the fit function instead of a model object, but I don't know I can create a model from a dictionary, except for way I tried.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you tried to apply `fit` to the name you gave the model.  YOu have to fit the *model* not its name.

```
dictionary_of_models = {'catboost':CatBoostClassifier(random_state=0,), 
                        'logistic_regression':LogisticRegression(random_state=0)}
for name, model in dictionary_of_models.items():
        print(name)
        dictionary_of_models[model]=model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementing Prune's answer, I believe you can avoid `items`. `dictionary_of_model[model]` would generate a KeyError given you are not passing the Key of the dictionary, but the value itself.

Please try:

```
for model in dictionary_of_models:
        print(model)
        dictionary_of_models[model] = dictionary_of_models[model].fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried and got no more the Attribute Errore above, but now I've a Key error: 'catboost', Segmentation Error (dump created)

Comment: Run again, and no core dump but only Key Error:'catboost'

Comment: Run again with "dictionary_of models.items()" and got "TypeError: unhashable type: 'CatBoostClassifier'"